# Why non-zero skewness is obtained from symmetric probability distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have generated a vector of data 'y' from a symmetric distribution (let's assume the Normal distribution). I have used R language for generating the data:

```
x = seq(60, 80, 0.01);
y = dnorm(x, mean=70, sd=1);
z = skewness(y);
```

Result:

```
z = 2.18358
```

Shouldn't I get 'z' equal to zero or very near to zero?

I have also increased the sampling rate from 0.01 to 0.0001 to 0.0000001 and got z from 2.18358 to 2.182749 to 2.182741. The same occurs with many other symmetric distributions that I have tested.

Comment: That's not how you generate a random sample from the normal distribution. It's the function `rnorm`you have to use. What you have done is just compute values of the density function at regular intervals. Those indeed form a skewed set of values.

Comment: @Raskolnikov You are right. I was mistaken.